How to merge objects and have good topology?
I am trying to model this part of a Tiger tank:

Here is my current progress:

As you can see, I have just joined 2 spheres into one.
How can I fix the topology? Do I have to do it manually or is there some tool that can do it easily?

There's Quad Remesher, but even that isn't perfect.

Unless this needs to be manifold for printing or suchlike, @Martynas Žiemys is on it.

Consider that you don't need to in this specific case. In real life those are separate parts, there is no reason to merge them in your 3d model - that would actually be less realistic. The gun probably needs to move.
That's how it looks:


Source: https://youtu.be/_JhKTKsdlB8?t=29

Yep, it definitely moves see https://youtu.be/rxCWnkRuH6Y?t=684
